# How to convert a column of type 'character' into minutes

Tags: r

I have a column labeled "game_length" that is character class (e.g. "2:15"). I am trying to turn this string into the number of total minutes (e.g. 135).

I have tried changing the class to date using lubridate package and trying to extract only the hours and minutes with strptime but am having no success. I feel like maybe I need to separate the column into "game_length_hours" and "game_length_mins" and then combine them into one by ("game_length_hours"*60) + (game_length_mins).

```
current format:
game_length
"2:15"
"2:28"
"3:02"

expected format:
game_length
135
148
182
```

Comment: One line mutate: `sum(as.numeric(str_split_fixed(game_length, ":", 2)) * c(60, 1))`

Comment: @csgroen this fills the column with all "NA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the input in the Note we convert to POSIXlt, multiply the hours by 60 and add to the minutes.  No packages are used.

```
with(as.POSIXlt(x, format = "%H:%M"), 60 * hour + min)
## [1] 135 148 182
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
x <- c("2:15", "2:28", "3:02")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split each string on `':'`, convert it to numeric, and then take the cross product with `c(60, 1)`. If you're not familiar with `%*%` it is the matrix multiplication operator. For vectors though, `a %*% b` is equal to `sum(a*b)`.

```
sapply(strsplit(game_length, ':'), function(x) as.numeric(x) %*% c(60, 1))
# [1] 135 148 182
```

Input:

```
game_length <- c("2:15", "2:28", "3:02")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you need, based on your example vector above.  It uses gsub to search and replace the pattern number colon number, returning the first number occurrence and converting from a string value to numeric, multiplying by 60 and then adding the second number occurring as seconds

```
game_length <- c("2:15","2:28","3:02")

as.numeric(gsub("^(\\d+):(\\d+)$","\\1",game_length))*60 +as.numeric(gsub("^(\\d+):(\\d+)$","\\2",game_length))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as.POSIXlt(), which transform string into date, and store each element of date as a list.

```
x <- "2:15"
y<-as.POSIXlt(x, format="%H:%M")
y$hour*60 + y$min
```

```
> unlist(y)
   sec    min   hour   mday    mon   year   wday   yday  isdst   zone 
   "0"   "15"    "2"   "16"    "1"  "119"    "6"   "46"    "0"  "JST" 
gmtoff 
    NA
```